# Google Oath on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-oauth

I'm working on a project with Framework7. I want to use the Google Oath on my localhost but I'm always getting this error.[Oath error when I'm on my localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkKhL.png) I added the localhost address in my API credentials on my Google Cloud Platform account. [As you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T349f.png)  But I still get this error. It works perfectly on my webserver. Why I'm getting this error on my localhost?

Comment: Did you whitelist localhost in google console?

Comment: @MarioNikolaus How can I do that? Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: Ah sorry, I just see you did do this already. What local hostnames did you enter in Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: @MarioNikolaus http://localhost:5500

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Auth API Javascript idpiframe initialization error on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42668299/google-auth-api-javascript-idpiframe-initialization-error-on-chrome)

Comment: @MarioNikolaus No, It doesn't answer. I had already done those steps.

Comment: You should then add to your question what have you tried so far